# Specific extrinsic stalls the parachain even though the collation is successfully produced

Tags: parachain, collator, stalled

We have the weird case that `extrinsics` in general work, but there is a specific extrinsic that stalls the parachain. See https://github.com/integritee-network/parachain/issues/222. This extrinsic sends a UMP-message to the relay chain requesting a [slot swap](https://github.com/integritee-network/pallets/blob/824c9a50dd8902697bd3e75ab6b5f7c3d663167f/xcm-transactor/src/lib.rs#L92).

Here are the logs with

- `-lparachain::collation-generation=trace`
- `-lparachain::approval-distribution=trace`
- `-lparachain::collator-protocol=trace`
- `-lbasic-authorship=trace -ltxpool=trace`

https://gist.github.com/clangenb/134b993a11e14f24f54893e08c86d959

Even more interesting, from these logs we can see that the collation was successful, and that that the collator's relay chain accepted it:

```
 cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Starting collation. relay_parent=0xf0bf2bf83f8216548ca4b5013a240a5786603949e259d9f837f88bba5aca9ddb at=0x026671e6c343fdbb5ab71a1026aa702cfe43d3409434589fbe1ff075ed551ef0
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.595  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x026671e6c343fdbb5ab71a1026aa702cfe43d3409434589fbe1ff075ed551ef0
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.600  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain]  Prepared block for proposing at 7823 (2 ms) [hash: 0xd933f8be0f9c03a26540f6420db2c740076c6678d9425b4ec150ae495c6fc6ca; parent_hash: 0x0266…1ef0; extrinsics (3): [0xcaec…3897, 0x470b…e13b, 0x1f79…cc15]]
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.606 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Processing assignments from a peer peer_id=12D3KooWLPKAJm3UECm9fVbgfw6WkrKUK64JayeruSMDcAHxXBXU num=1
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.606 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Checked assignment source=Peer(PeerId("12D3KooWLPKAJm3UECm9fVbgfw6WkrKUK64JayeruSMDcAHxXBXU")) message_subject=MessageSubject(0xbd08cd884606f9765a9d92ee6c2d00a168ea655c0c33db00a17dca33a989a5ae, 7, ValidatorIndex(72)) result=Accepted
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.606 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Reputation change for peer reputation=BenefitMinorFirst("Valid message with new information") peer_id=PeerId("12D3KooWLPKAJm3UECm9fVbgfw6WkrKUK64JayeruSMDcAHxXBXU")
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.606 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Sending an assignment to peers block_hash=0xbd08cd884606f9765a9d92ee6c2d00a168ea655c0c33db00a17dca33a989a5ae claimed_candidate_index=7 local=false num_peers=3
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.607  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura: [Parachain]  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 7823. Hash now 0x78a4a05bc8da537c1e3d26f21d1c4dae934a551c4d0e870051645b5116847acc, previously 0xd933f8be0f9c03a26540f6420db2c740076c6678d9425b4ec150ae495c6fc6ca.
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.608  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] PoV size { header: 0.1796875kb, extrinsics: 5.7197265625kb, storage_proof: 9.3466796875kb }
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.608  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Parachain] ✨ Imported #7823 (0x78a4…7acc)
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.608  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Compressed PoV size: 9.5498046875kb
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.608  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: [Parachain] Produced proof-of-validity candidate. block_hash=0x78a4a05bc8da537c1e3d26f21d1c4dae934a551c4d0e870051645b5116847acc
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.611 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collation-generation: [Relaychain] candidate is generated candidate_hash=0x936f64b18fbf2ba1ccd2979b75219731c5e7ecbb0e934e8a455c9319d60d322b pov_hash=0x84e1b30af67914e2133f9362055efa0eae2ce3afcf5aee095369099f58b8b2b1 relay_parent=0xf0bf2bf83f8216548ca4b5013a240a5786603949e259d9f837f88bba5aca9ddb para_id=2267 traceID=195974902640512596657898995620943861553
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.611 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Received session info session_index=31556
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.611 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] Accepted collation, connecting to validators. para_id=2267 relay_parent=0xf0bf…9ddb candidate_hash=0x936f64b18fbf2ba1ccd2979b75219731c5e7ecbb0e934e8a455c9319d60d322b pov_hash=0x84e1b30af67914e2133f9362055efa0eae2ce3afcf5aee095369099f58b8b2b1 core=CoreIndex(41) current_validators=[Public(dea7cae27e5dfb239a7ca5fb0649568b57afc08ed2ec5e538d4a3abb786fbc3c (5H6eLEHx...)), Public(fcf408d2b46082efffea4ddd78d114e021439b47d4a5848e15f6d3e5eca44c2e (5HnNRAfr...)), Public(4c0e2bd29d0d14bf81da32c79492dbc2bd97a594f34c982047b8a2ee4d035865 (5DnRhudq...)), Public(3a56f3c36ae08f7cfdeea6d340aa45ebd6b379f47267ca78837749054dec7b03 (5DPCTuQm...)), Public(e6e40731962e2834867cc4f482308cc34e4579ee1a5e1667c3ec36d96b36a971 (5HHScHPf...))] traceID=195974902640512596657898995620943861553
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.618 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Processing approvals from a peer peer_id=12D3KooWLPKAJm3UECm9fVbgfw6WkrKUK64JayeruSMDcAHxXBXU num=1
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.619 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Checked approval peer_id=PeerId("12D3KooWLPKAJm3UECm9fVbgfw6WkrKUK64JayeruSMDcAHxXBXU") message_subject=MessageSubject(0xbd08cd884606f9765a9d92ee6c2d00a168ea655c0c33db00a17dca33a989a5ae, 9, ValidatorIndex(147)) result=Accepted
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.619 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Reputation change for peer reputation=BenefitMinorFirst("Valid message with new information") peer_id=PeerId("12D3KooWLPKAJm3UECm9fVbgfw6WkrKUK64JayeruSMDcAHxXBXU")
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.619 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Sending an approval to peers block_hash=0xbd08cd884606f9765a9d92ee6c2d00a168ea655c0c33db00a17dca33a989a5ae candidate_index=9 local=false num_peers=3
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.639 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Processing assignments from a peer peer_id=12D3KooWQxG51uMhJVwSJqULapVorQRbqZ4BzkAJ2VosDQjVDifT num=1
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.639 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Checked assignment source=Peer(PeerId("12D3KooWQxG51uMhJVwSJqULapVorQRbqZ4BzkAJ2VosDQjVDifT")) message_subject=MessageSubject(0xbd08cd884606f9765a9d92ee6c2d00a168ea655c0c33db00a17dca33a989a5ae, 10, ValidatorIndex(178)) result=Accepted
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.639 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain] Reputation change for peer reputation=BenefitMinorFirst("Valid message with new information") peer_id=PeerId("12D3KooWQxG51uMhJVwSJqULapVorQRbqZ4BzkAJ2VosDQjVDifT")
Jul 05 14:05:18 lease-swap-02 integritee-collator[72042]: 2023-07-05 14:05:18.639 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: [Relaychain]
```

The collator runs on `polkadot-v0.9.42`
The runtime runs on `polkadot-v0.9.37`: https://github.com/integritee-network/parachain/tree/1.5.35/polkadot-parachains/shell-runtime

It happens with the live Kusama network.

It seems that the UMP part is indeed the problem. If the same dispatchable is executed with non-root origin, the block is successfully produced, and I get a `BadOrigin` error. So, can the executed xcm operations indeed prevent the relay chain from backing a block?

**Edit:** After additional investigation, I can confirm that:

- It works on a rococo-local-dev [setup](https://github.com/integritee-network/parachain/issues/222#issuecomment-1625604991), where the collator's host is running on polkadot-v0.9.37.
- The collator's substrate version does make a [difference](https://github.com/integritee-network/parachain/issues/222#issue-1789714752). If the host runs on v0.9.42, I get a UMP error that, however, doesn't stall the chain.
- XCM in general seems to work
- I made sure that the parachain account on the relay chain has some funds.

**Edit:** Updated the logs with a more verbose log additionally containing: basic-authorship and txpool.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to be stalling your chain, isn't it ?

Comment: After speaking with the author it seems that the node works again after clearing the txpool (restarting the node). We might want to set a few more log targets, I would say `basic-authorship` and `txpool` then update the linked logs :)

Comment: Updated the logs with the additional flags. Nothing seems suspicious to me yet.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that an update to polkadot-v0.9.42 of the runtime did solve the issue. It is not clear yet why this resolved the issue. However, this included the change to XCM v3.

Comment: Thanks for posting an update :)